# link two pickers with a button and one result swift

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I want the user to do this: when they select an item from the first picker and the item on the other picker and click on the button they get the result in a text field. How can I do that?

I already created two pickers, text field, and one button. For example: if the user selects from the first spinner their name and the second spinner their id, when they click to the button the text view will show their telephone number.

This is what I did so far:

```
// //  ViewController.swift //  test001 // //  Created by Ahmed  N. on
7/14/1438 AH. //  Copyright © 1438 Ahmed  N. All rights reserved. //

import UIKit

class Viewkm: UIViewController,
UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var array1: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var array2: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var result: UITextField!

    var array:NSArray = []
    var array12:NSArray = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        array = ["3","2","1"]
        array12 = ["Nasser","meachal","Ahmed"]
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if (pickerView.tag == 1){
            return array.count
        }else{
            return array12.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if (pickerView.tag == 1){
            return "\(array[row])"
        }else{
            return "\(array12[row])"
        }
    }

    public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }

    @IBAction func getResult(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var select1 = array[array1.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        var select2 = array12[array2.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]

        if (select1 == "1") && (select2 = "Ahmed")  {
            getResult.setTitle("Telephone number...", result: .Normal)
        }
    }
}
```

**** Update ****

> ```
> //    //  ViewController.swift    //  test001    //    //  Created       by Ahmed  N. on 7/14/1438 AH.    //  Copyright © 1438 Ahmed  N. All
> ```
>
> rights reserved.    //
>
> import UIKit
>
> // ++++++++++++++ i gut here an error    class Viewkm:
>   UIViewController,
>   UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {
>
> ```
> @IBOutlet weak var array1: UIPickerView!
> @IBOutlet weak var array2: UIPickerView!
> //this is a text failt that i want to set tge resut in
> @IBOutlet weak var result: UITextField!
>
> // i did these two 
>
> var selectedRow1 : Int
> var selectedRow2 : Int
>
> var array:NSArray = []
> var array12:NSArray = []
>
> // array fo numbers
> var arrayNumbers:NSArray = []
>
>
> override func viewDidLoad() {
>     super.viewDidLoad()
>     array = ["3","2","1"]
>     array12 = ["Nasser","meachal","Ahmed"]
>     arrayNumbers = ["400","500","4000"]
>
>
>
>
>
>
> }
>
>
>
> func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int,   inComponent component: Int) {
>     if (pickerView.tag == 1){
>         self.selectedRow1 = row
>     }else{
>         self.selectedRow1 = row
>     }
> }
>
>
> override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
>     super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
>     // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
> }
>
> func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
>     return 1
> }
>
> func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
>     if (pickerView.tag == 1){
>         return array.count
>     }else{
>         return array12.count
>     }
> }
>
> func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
>     if (pickerView.tag == 1){
>         return "\(array[row])"
>     }else{
>         return "\(array12[row])"
>     }
>
>
> }
> public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
>     return 1
> }
>
>
>
>
> @IBAction func getResult(_ sender: UIButton) {
>     var select1 = array[self.selectedRow1]
>     var select2 = array12[self.selectedRow2]
>
>
>     // error syaed : binert opreater "==" cannot be applied to type "any" or "String"
>     if (select1 == "1") && (select2 = "Ahmed")  {
>         //And you can show the number from array list
>
>         // ******************** error sayed : cannot call value of non-function type String
>         result.text("Telephone number...\(self.arrayNumber[self.selectedrow1])", result: .Normal)
>     }
> }
>
>
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pickerview delegate method for this.

```
  //those two for selected pickerView rows
    var selectedRow1 : Int
    var selectedRow2 : Int
    //this array for the numbers. You should fill this array with users number maybe.
    var arrayNumbers:NSArray = []
    //pickerView delegate method, the row keyword shows which row is selected
    optional func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int,   inComponent component: Int) { 
    if (pickerView.tag == 1){
                self.selectedRow1 = row
            }else{
                self.selectedRow1 = row
            }
    }
    //your button action be like this
    @IBAction func getResult(_ sender: UIButton) {
            var select1 = array[self.selectedRow1]
            var select2 = array12[self.selectedRow2]
            //your arrray type is Any
            if (String(select1) == "1") && (String(select2) = "Ahmed")  {
    //And you can show the number from array list
                getResult.setTitle("Telephone number...\(self.arrayNumber[self.selectedrow1])", result: .Normal)
            }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the replay ... it doesn't work for me I gut an error in the Button

Comment: my mistake sorry about that. i updated too. Contains of select array[] and array12[] are Any. You should try my my edited answer. Or you should define the arrays:
`var array : [String] = []
var array12 : [String] = []`